# bxslider slide transition difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am currently using the jQuery plugin [isoSlider](http://iosscripts.com/iosslider/), I am trying to create a delay slide transition delay like the slide [Kenzo](https://www.kenzo.com/en/) where there is a slight delay when the image slides into the centre.

Based on the documentation on the BXslide site, I can't find any option function which will enable me to do this.

[Example of my slider](http://iamnatesmithen.com/dev/iosslider%202/_demos/_examples/7-Centered-Slides/2-Background-Images/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
                snapToChildren: true,
                desktopClickDrag: true,
                infiniteSlider: true,
                snapSlideCenter: true,
                scrollbarMargin: '0',
                scrollbarBorderRadius: '0',
                keyboardControls: true,
                //autoSlide: true,
                scrollbar: true,
                navNextSelector: $('.next'),
                navPrevSelector: $('.prev'),
                navSlideSelector: $('.selectors .item'),
                onSlideChange: slideChange,
                stageCSS: {
                    overflow: 'visible'
                }
            });

        });
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: I don't think you are using bxslider. Clearly it is iosslider.

Comment: @maximus oops just noticed i uploaded the wrong link. isoSlider i mean.